Как сохранить параметры с одинаковыми названиями в разных переменных?
Мне нужно получить 2 переменные из параметров с одинаковыми названиями "name" из json. Первая переменная - "name1" из первого name, вторая переменная - "name2" из второго name. Как это сделать?

{"list":[{"name":"Oleg","date":"1705681456195","user":"710953882"},{"name":"Nikolai","date":"1719591128193","user":"607754142"}]}


name1=data['list'][0]['name']; name2=data['list'][1]['name']

Зачем отдельные переменные, когда можно список?
